# Is there a way to display promotion status in Jenkins next to each build history?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, promoted-builds

In Jenkins we can promote the build for each build number.
I want to display the status of promotion in the right side of each build in build history box?
Otherwise is it possible to list all the builds which needs to be promoted in a seperate page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly where they are supposed to be displayed. **After** the promotion has been executed, you will see a promotion star there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got it! I want to know what are all the other statuses can be displayed here.

Comment: The three that you can see on my screenshot are [**JobConfigHistory**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin), [**Build Trigger Badge**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Trigger+Badge+Plugin) and [**Disk Usage**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disk+Usage+Plugin). You can also use [**Groovy Postbuild**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) for a lot of custom badges in the build history

Comment: To see a status, you must select something in the Promotion step, e.g. select an Icon such as "Green star"